# Jest doesn't match any test with --findRelatedTests and lint-staged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I have configured lint-staged in my `create-react-app` so it runs tests with staged files.My tests are running without any issue, it only fails to find tests with `--findRelatedTests`.

*jest.config.js*

`currentTestDirectory` - can be `admin|business|consumer|core|shared`.

```
{
    verbose: true,
    roots: [`<rootDir>/tests/__tests__/${currentTestDirectory}`],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'],
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    resetMocks: true,
    setupFiles: ['react-app-polyfill/jsdom'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts', '<rootDir>/tests/mocks.ts'],
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    testMatch: [`<rootDir>/tests/__tests__/${currentTestDirectory}/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', 'scripts'],
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$': '<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js',
      '^.+\\.css$': '<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js',
      '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js',
      '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      'node_modules/(?!(react-dnd|core-dnd|@react-dnd|dnd-core|react-dnd-html5-backend|react-dnd-touch-backend|uuid)/)',
    ],
    watchPlugins: ['jest-watch-typeahead/filename', 'jest-watch-typeahead/testname'],
  }
```

And the *package.json* file.

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "test:staged": "CI=true node scripts/test.js --bail --findRelatedTests",
}
"dependencies": {
  "jest": "^29.3.1",
  // other
}
```

And this is my *.lintstagedrc file*

```
{
  "**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)": [
    "eslint",
    "prettier --write",
    "npm run test:staged"
  ]
}
```

This is my app folder structure for your convenience to get all the details.

```
├── README.md
├── apps
├── build
├── config
├── core
├── jest.config.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
├── scripts
├── shared
├── tests
├── tools
├── tsconfig.json
└── version.json
```

`git status` shows my changed file that has been tested.

> modified:   apps/admin/src/pages/login/index.tsx

When I am running `git commit -am "Some message"`, I see pre-commit hook exists with code 1.

```
✔ Preparing lint-staged...
❯ Running tasks for staged files...
  ❯ .lintstagedrc — 1 files
    ❯ **/*.+(ts|tsx|js) — 1 files
      ✔ eslint
      ✔ prettier --write
      ✖ npm run test:staged [FAILED]
      ◼ git add
↓ Skipped because of errors from tasks. [SKIPPED]
✔ Reverting to original state because of errors...
✔ Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ npm run test:staged:

> grailpay-web@0.1.0 test:staged
> CI=true node scripts/test.js --bail --findRelatedTests /Users/felixmanus/Desktop/grailpay-web-app/apps/admin/src/pages/login/index.tsx

Running all the available tests

No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
No files found in /Users/felixmanus/Desktop/grailpay-web-app.

Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
Jest Documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Pattern: /Users/felixmanus/Desktop/grailpay-web-app/apps/admin/src/pages/login/index.tsx - 0 matches
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

I have done a lot of research and also found a lot of cases where `--findRelatedTests` option is working properly with `lint-staged`.I guess there can be some configuration I am missing or set wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped add extra `--` after `npm run test` and `--passWithNoTests`

**lint-staged.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  '*.{ts,tsx}': ['eslint', 'npm run test -- --findRelatedTests --passWithNoTests'],
};
```

**package.json**

```js
scripts: {
  "test": "jest",
}
```

Related for jest v28.0.0: "[BREAKING] Exit with status 1 if no tests are found with --findRelatedTests flag" https://github.com/jestjs/jest/releases/tag/v28.0.0-alpha.5

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the internals of the jest and figured out how they internally run `findRelatedTests`.It turns out the mistake was in my `jest.config.js`, particularly with `roots` option.The path searching filter relies on config.roots.

for additional info check it here - [https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/main/packages/jest-core/src/SearchSource.ts#L68](https://jest%20github)

So in the end, changing the roots to include also `<rootDir>` solved my issue.